# How to cut a string into 2 parts? In C#

Tags: c#

So I am trying to find a way to split strings into 2 different strings,
example:
`string str1 = "Hello there!";`

then I want it to split it into 2 strings

```
string str2 = "Hello";
string str3 = "there!";
```

Thank you!

Here is the code I am using, I am pulling text from pastebin and trying to split it into multiple parts:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string pulledInfo = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/cqmrCa0m");

        Console.WriteLine("Split with multiple separators");
        string gotInfo = pulledInfo;
        string[] multiArray = gotInfo.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',',});
        foreach (string author in multiArray)
        {
            if (author.Trim() != "")
                Console.WriteLine(author);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried at least?

Comment: `str1.Split(" ")`

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array using [`string.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split):

```cs
string str1 = "Hello there!";
string[] text = str1.Split(' ');

string str2 = text[0];
string str3 = text[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Hello there!";
string[] strings = str.Split(' ');
string yourstr1= strings [0];
string yourstr2= strings [1];
```